# Why do I have to prefix attributes from imported XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following two XSDS, test.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1"     
  targetNamespace="http://www.test.com" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.test.com/ns1" schemaLocation="test1.xsd"/>
    <element name="Root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Child" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
            <attribute ref="ns1:myAttrib1" use="required"/>
            <attribute ref="ns1:myAttrib2" use="required"/>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

and test1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <attribute name="myAttrib1" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="myAttrib2" type="string"/>
</schema>
```

The instance document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.test.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
  ns1:myAttrib1="1" ns1:myAttrib2="2">
    <Child>Child 1</Child>
</Root>
```

Now, using Xerces 2.11.0, I have to prefix attributes `myAttrib1` and `myAttrib2` with `ns1` for it to pass validation. At first thought I felt this was not in conformance with the schema definitions (due to the `attributeFormDefault="unqualified"` in `ns1`), but giving it a second thought it kind of makes sense. Here's how I understand it: the prefix is necessary because attributes `myAttrib1` and `myAttrib2` are not defined in the <del>`targetNamespace`</del> default namespace where they are used, i.e. they're not defined in `xmlns="http://www.test.com"`.

Here's my questions: 1) have I understood the necessity of prefix said attributes correctly, and 2) where in the W3C rec. may I find a passage that describes this behavior? Thanks. :)

UPDATE: I came across the following passage

> The final two attributes (elementFormDefault and attributeFormDefault)
>   are a facility provided by W3C XML Schema to control, within a single
>   schema, whether attributes and elements are considered by default to
>   be qualified (in a namespace). This differentiation between qualified
>   and unqualified can be indicated by specifying the default values, as
>   above, but also when defining the elements and attributes, by adding a
>   form attribute of value qualified or unqualified.
>
> It is important to note that only local elements and attributes can be
>   specified as unqualified. All globally defined elements and attributes
>   must always be qualified.

found over at [xml.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/29/schemas/part1.html?page=8). Another interesting source is [zvon.org](http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_attributeFormDefault.html). So this really backs up the accepted answer. However, I have yet to see exactly where the (notoriously cryptic) W3C rec. mentions this in detail. After all, they are the governing body in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Correct. However, the `attributeFormDefault` and `elementFormDefault` apply only to **locally** defined attributes and elements. In other words, those that are not immediate children of **schema** and **redefine**, nested within other schema components.

2) [Section 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAttribute_Declarations).2 shows that ref must be a QName. In general, everywhere in the XSD you see a ref attribute, it'll be of QName type.

Answer (score 2):

Top-level element and attribute declarations in a schema are always in the targetNamespace of the schema.  The `elementFormDefault` and `attributeFormDefault` apply only to anonymous element/attribute declarations that are nested inside a complex type.  If your `test.xsd` schema did not specify `elementFormDefault="qualified"` then the `Child` element inside the complex type would not be in a namespace, and the instance document would need to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Root xmlns:ns="http://www.test.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
  ns1:myAttrib1="1" ns1:myAttrib2="2">
    <Child>Child 1</Child>
</Root>
```

Furthermore, attributes that are in a namespace *must* be prefixed - the default `xmlns="..."` namespace declaration only applies to elements.  Thus

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Root xmlns="http://www.test.com/nl1" xmlns:ns="http://www.test.com" 
  myAttrib1="1" myAttrib2="2">
    <ns:Child>Child 1</ns:Child>
</ns:Root>
```

is *not* valid - myAttrib1 and myAttrib2 are not in a namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I edited my (admittedly badly phrased) question re. the part about targetNamespace. Re. the case of elementFormDefault="unqualified", I have earlier been under the impression that it was the usage of a default namespace that controlled this behavior. So thanks for bringing my attention to this mechanism. +1