# Trouble understanding particular XSD validation result (Xceres)

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm implementing a XML solution conforming to two externally provided XSDs. First, we have ns1.xsd:

```
<schema xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/ns2" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.test.com/ns2" 
        schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/ns2.xsd"/>
    <element name="Root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Child" type="ns2:ChildType" 
                         minOccurs="0"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <attribute ref="ns2:field3" use="optional"/>
    </element>
</schema>
```

and ns2.xsd:

```
<schema xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/ns2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/ns2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="ChildType">
        <attribute name="field1" type="string" use="optional"/>
        <attribute name="field2" type="string" use="optional"/>
    </complexType>
    <attribute name="field3" type="string"/>
</schema>
```

Over at [liquid-technologies.com](http://www.liquid-technologies.com) there is a [tutorial showing how XSDs using referenced types](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx) should be implemented. Following that logic, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
      xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/ns2" 
      ns2:field3="test">
    <Child ns2:field1="test" ns2:field2="test"/>
</Root>
```

which validates using Xerces 2.11.0. If I change `attributeFormDefault="unqualified"` in ns2.xsd I have to drop the namespace prefixes in the implementation to get it to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.test.com/ns1" 
      xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/ns2" 
      ns2:field3="test">
    <Child field1="test" field2="test"/>
</Root>
```

As I [asked a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250819/why-do-i-have-to-prefix-attributes-from-imported-xsd), `field3` is (correctly) still prefixed. Now I wonder:

1. What is the true difference between `field1` and `field2` in contrast to `field3`? Why do Xceres force me to omit prefixes for `field1` and `field2`? Is it because `field1` and `field2` are really part of a type while `field3` is a reference to an attribute?
2. How do the receiver tell what namespace attributes `field1` and `field2` belongs to in the second case?

(And if anyone know what part of the W3C recs that describe these rules, I'd be really greatful for that too.)

**Additional info**

I feel an urge for pointing out the consequences of this example. In case 1 `field1` and `field2` are prefixed with `ns2` which clearly establish them as attribute names in the `ns2`-namespace. In case 2, where neither of said attribute names are prefixed, it is hard to come to any other conclusion than these attributes belongs to the default (`ns1`) namespace.

Why does this matter? Well, this matters because it has effectivly turned `attributeFormDefault` into a namespace qualifier. I have serious problems understanding how this was the intention of the W3C committee, and thus I consider it a bug. If anyone can enlighten me, I'd be thrilled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes that are not prefixed are generally taken as being in no namespace. They are not in the default namespace. (I say generally, because there are some people who prefer a different interpretation, like that they are in an unspecified namespace, but such distinctions are too subtle for me.)

When you say attributeFormDefault="unqualified", locally-declared attributes in the schema document for ns2 will be in no namespace, which means they must appear in the instance with no prefix.

As for ns2:field3, this is a little odd because there doesn't seem to be a declaration for the attribute. But if there were one, it would have to be a global attribute declaration, and global attributes always go in the target namespace of the containing schema document.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight! My mistake on not including the missing ns2:field3-declaration. I've added it now. Actually, I did see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903768/unqualified-xsd-global-attribute-references post, but didn't realize the consequences of it. So I guess the conclusion that (element|attribute)FormDefault (in a sense) implicitly controls namespace belonging is correct after all?

Comment: Edit: elementFormDefault don't have this effect, as non-prefixed elements end up in the default namespace. I also have a bit of trouble interpreting the following: "A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. _Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear_." (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting, my emphasis).

Comment: [Side issue.]  The distinction between "not known to be in any particular namespace" and "known not to be in any namespace at all" doesn't seem subtle to me.  Not knowing whether X is married, or not knowing what salary X makes, are not at all the same things as knowing that X is not married or that X makes no salary at all.  True, the Namespaces spec doesn't provide very good terminology for this; that's why some people prefer to speak of qualified and unqualified names, meaning Qnames whose expanded form has a non-null or a null namespace value.

Comment: What the base specs say is that they aren't going to define what namespace an unprefixed attribute is in, that's up to the application to decide. That's a committee compromise (we can't agree so we'll leave it to the user.) What implementations do, and what most processing specs like XSLT and XQuery say, is that unprefixed attributes are presented as being not in any namespace.

Comment: See?  You don't find the distinction too subtle at all.  You just don't much like it :)

Comment: And I don't find it useful. If you live your life believing that unprefixed attributes are in no namespace, you're going to get along just fine, at least until you come across wierdnesses like the way DOM represents xmlns="abc".